# ASP.NET CLR Not Enabled

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, clr

I am getting the following error on my new installation of ASP.Net and SQL Server when I run my app:

```
 Execution of user code in the .NET Framework is disabled. Enable "clr enabled" configuration option
```

I have tried to fix it by running this:

```
 use dasolPSDev;

 sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
 go
 RECONFIGURE
 go
 sp_configure 'clr enabled'
 go
```

But then I get:

```
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
 Incorrect syntax near 'sp_config
```

Comment: From Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2120850/error-message-after-you-restore-a-sql-server-2008-32-bit-dynamics-pos

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Try this

```
use dasolPSDev;

EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
 go
 RECONFIGURE
 go
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'
 go
```

Comment: How long does this script normally take to execute? because mine, I have had it run more than 1 minute and still no result..!!

Comment: How to run this

Answer (score 30):

Simplified version of jams' solution which worked for me (SQL Server 2012):

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254506%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, but this works for me (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with 
sp_configure @configname=clr_enabled, @configvalue=1

then restarted the sql server. it worked

Answer (score 0):

The following steps fixed my problem.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Connect to your database instance.
3. File > New > Query with Current Connection.
4. Paste the following into the editor (reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-enabled-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled';  
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled' , '1';  
RECONFIGURE;
```

5. Click Execute.