# Can you enable Sql Cache Dependency on a database and/or table solely via Sql scripts?

Tags: .net, sql-server

We would like to enable Sql Cache Dependency on a database and a few tables, but we would like to avoid using aspnet_regsql.exe if possible.  The database is already in our staging environment and it will be easier to just send the admins a Sql script instead of requiring batch files as well.  Is it possible to enable Sql Cache Dependency entirely through Sql scripts, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that aspnet_regsql.exe includes options to generate SQL Scripts for "Applications Services" and "Session State", but doesn't for "Cache Dependency" would heavily imply, to me, that generating such scripts isn't doable.

Comment: Technically you could run the command against a test database and trace all the changes made to the database using SQL Server Profiler.  Then combine those trace scripts into a build script for publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aspnet_reqsql.exe doesn't really do anything to 'enable' SqlCacheDependency. SqlCacheDependency is based on [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) which uses [`SqlNotificationRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqlnotificationrequest.aspx) which is the .net side of a [Query Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx). Query Notifications are enabled always and cannot be disabled. Query Notifications uses [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to deliver the notification, which is also enabled by default, but which *can* be disabled in a database. The typical operation that will disable Service Broker in a database is attach or restore. To make sure you do not fall victim to this problem, all you need to do (and this is exactly what aspnet_regsql does) is to run this:

```
ALTER DATABASE [<dbname>] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Another problem that might occur is that the EXECUTE AS context required by Service Broker message delivery may be busted. For a lengthy discussion on how the EXECUTE AS can get busted, see [SQL Server stops loading assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034969/sql-server-stops-loading-assembly/7338444#7338444), and the solution is trivial:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<dbname>] TO sa;
```

And finally, if you want to understand how all these work, read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/).